# Posting KnockoutJS observable array to PHP through Ajax

Tags: php, knockout.js

I have a KnockoutJS observable array which is prepared at the client side:

```
var invoices = function(invoiced_article_number,invoiced_article_name){
        this.invoicedArticleNumber = invoiced_article_number;
        this.invoicedArticleName = invoiced_article_name;
    };
```

Array is initialized on page load:

```
this.selectedInvoices = ko.observableArray();
```

And, On a click of a button certain elements are pushed in the array:

```
self.selectedInvoices.push(new invoices(self.selectedArticle().articleNumber,self.selectedArticle().articleName));
```

I want to pass this observable array to PHP through a Ajax post request to insert the data in MySQL. I have tried converting it to java script object using following code but i keep getting null in PHP.

```
var data = ko.toJS({"data":self.selectedInvoices});
```

Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "URL.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {invoiceData: data},
                cache: false,
                success: function(returnedData) {}
            });
```

PHP Code:

```
$invoice_data = trim($_POST['invoiceData']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ko.toJSON` to serialise your view-model into something which can be sent to PHP. Try:

```
var data = ko.toJSON({"data":self.selectedInvoices});
```

This will send a string representing a serialised state of your view-model to PHP. You can then deserialise it in PHP with:

```
$invoice_data = json_decode(trim($_POST['invoiceData']));
```